# How can I calculate the probability that a string with n unique characters contains each character from a random string?

Tags: probability

If I have a string that has *n* unique characters (out of a potential set of 62 [A-Za-z0-9], 26+26+10), how can I calculate the probability that the string contains each character in another string, when that string is made of 9 random characters (all from that 62-character set) and a 10th character with 16 possible values: [.26AEIMQUYcgkosw]?

Comment: Which of the $16$ characters are candidates for the tenth character?

Comment: Welcome to maths SE. What have you tried?

Comment: @EkeshKumar, the 10th character can be any of .26AEIMQUYcgkosw

Comment: @AlainRemillard I can't really get my head around where to start.